# Print entire line of key=value pairs if field in line meets condition - awk

Tags: awk, expression

I have logs with data containing key=value pairs separated by space.

```
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=100.00
```

I want to print the entire line, where the SuccessRate is < 99.

So far I've used awk to figure out where the SuccessRate is < 99, but it only prints the field itself, not the entire line:

```
awk '/SuccessRate/ {print $NF}' file | awk -F "=" '$2<=99{print ;}'
```

Doing this prints out :

```
SuccessRate=98.64
SuccessRate=0.00  
SuccessRate=16.09
...
```

However, I want to print the entire line when the condition is met:

```
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
...
```

Not sure how to do it without the extra pipe. Additionally, how would I do this if the field I was interested in was not the last field in the line? i.e. what if I wanted to print if `TxPkts` met a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `match` function in `awk`:

```bash
awk -v s='SuccessRate=' 'match($0, s "[.[0-9]+") && substr($0,RSTART+length(s))+0 <= 99' file

time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `SuccessRate` could be in any field:

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                      # iterate all field
        split($i,a,/=/)                       # split on =
        if(a[1]=="SuccessRate" && a[2]<99) {  # on success
            print                             # output and
            next                              # next line please
        }
    }
}' file
```

If it is always in the last field:

```
$ awk '{
    split($NF,a,/=/)                          # split and check last field only
    if(a[1]=="SuccessRate"&&a[2]<99)
        print
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You never want to make two calls to `awk` with a pipe in between when a single call to `awk` will do (which is virtually every time). In your case you can simply save the last field and the use `sub` to remove `SuccessRate=` leaving the value which you can compare against `99`, e.g.

```bash
awk '{f=$NF; sub(/SuccessRate=/,"",f); if (f+0<99) print}'
```

With your input in `pairs.txt`, you would receive no output from:

```
$ awk '{f=$NF; sub(/SuccessRate=/,"",f); if (f+0<99) print}' pairs.txt
```

but would receive output for any value where `SuccessRate < 99`. The `f+0` ensures `f` is treated as a number and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only. Please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk` version of it.

```bash
awk -v RS=' SuccessRate=[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?\\n' '
prev && RT && split(RT,arr,"=") && arr[2]<99{
  print prev
}
NF{ prev=$0 }
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Ok, it took a double-look, but ingenious use of RS. I wouldn't have thought to approach it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
$ cat file
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=19 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=198.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=209 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=399 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=398.64
```

One `awk` idea:

```
attrib='SuccessRate'

awk -v attrib="${attrib}" '
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                     # loop through attrib=value pairs
      split($i,a,"=")                       # split on "="; a[1]=attrib a[2]=value
      if (a[1]==attrib && a[2] < 99) {      # if we have a match then ...
         print                              # print current line and ...
         next                               # skip to next line of input
      }
  }
}
' file
```

For `attrib='SuccessRate'` this generates:

```
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=209 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
```

For `attrib='TxPkts'` this generates:

```
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=19 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=198.64
```

OP could modify this further to include parameterizing the `99` (eg, `-v limit='99'` and `if (a[1]==attirb && a[2]<limit)`); parameterizing the comparison operator (`<` in this case) could be done with a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F" |=" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="SuccessRate" && $(i+1)<99) print}' input_file
time=2022-08-10T16:03:23Z Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time=2022-08-10T16:03:23Z Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's key=value pairs in  the input as you have, I find it best to create an array, `f[]` below, holding that mapping and then you can access the values by their keys (names) in whatever order you like, for testing, printing, modifying, etc. e.g.:

```
awk '
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            split($i,keyval,"=")
            f[keyval[1]] = keyval[2]
        }
    }
    f["SuccessRate"] < 99
' file
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=98.64
time="2022-08-10T16:03:23Z" Event=xyz TxPkts=9 DroppedPkts=0 FailedRetries=0 SuccessRate=0.00
```